# SObjectException

Tags: apex, exception

As per my understanding, the below code should throw
**System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field**, but instead it updated the account phone without any exception can someone please help me to understand the same?

```
public static void SObjectException1() {

    Account act = [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name='GenePoint' LIMIT 1];
    act.phone = '1234567810';
    update act;
}
```

is it a best practice to not query the fields which we are going to update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set any fields you want on queried objects. What you cannot do is get their values. This code would throw the error you expect:

```
Account record= [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name='GenePoint' LIMIT 1];
system.debug(record.Phone);
```